# How is the solution for the Laplacian in three dimensions for Polar symmetry?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

I have a problem in which i have a sphere in which the potential for that sphere is defined on its surface, but there is polar symmetry, how am I supposed to get the answer, becuase usually (with azimutal symmetry) the third term on the laplacian is zero, and then using the radial equation and the legendre polynomials you get the general solution. In this case that there's just polar symmetry how is the solution defined?

Comment: What's "polar symmetry"? Independence of $\theta$ but possible dependence on $\phi$?

Comment: Exactly, independence in $\theta$ and dependence on $\phi$

Comment: Are you familiar, or have heard about the spherical harmonics? They are the more general solution to such problems

Comment: I meant to post this along with my comment, its background on spherical harmonics http://www.uvm.edu/~cems/keoughst/LectureNotes141/Topic_07_(ElectrostaticFieldProblems).pdf

Comment: Yes I have heard of them, even I have seen the answer with spherical harmonics, but what I dont figure out is how to treat such functions when I have independence on $\theta$?